# How do I iterate and match an IP against IP ranges (cidr) in python?

Tags: python, loops, ip, pattern-matching, match

I have a table with `'State'` and the associate IP CIDR range associate with that state.

*TABLE A*

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID         | State       | IP_subnet           |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1          |      CA     |    192.168.1.0/24   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2          |      TX     |    172.68.7.0/24    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3          |      NY     |    61.141.47.0/24   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to iterate through the table below and match the `IP` field against `IP_subnet` field.

*TABLE B*

```
| ID         |          IP           | 
--------------------------------------
| 1          |      61.141.47.1      |
--------------------------------------
| 2          |      192.168.1.48     | 
--------------------------------------
| 3          |      172.68.7.124     |
--------------------------------------
| 4          |      40.32.123.212    |
--------------------------------------
```

Below is the results I am going for: (matching the associated `State` to the `IP`)

```
| ID         |          IP           |      State  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1          |      61.141.47.1      |      null   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2          |      192.168.1.48     |      CA     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3          |      172.68.7.124     |      TX     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4          |      40.32.123.212    |      NY     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I know the code below would work for 1 value. How do I iterate through a column of `IPs` against another one?

```py
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv4Network

IPv4Address('172.68.7.124') in IPv4Network('172.68.7.0/24')
```

FYi

- 192.168.1.0/24 == range [192.168.1.0 TO 192.168.1.255]
- 172.68.7.0/24 == range [172.68.7.0 TO 172.68.7.255]

## initialize list of lists

data = [[1, 'CA', '192.168.1.0/24'], [2, 'TX', '172.68.7.0/24'], ['juli', 14], [3, NY, 61.141.47.0/24]]

## Create the pandas DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'State', 'IP_subnet'])

Comment: How is your table data store in python?  Is a it a pandas data frame?

Comment: yes it is in panda

Comment: @whodat post you df data as pandas result instead of tables generated by string

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi i have not actually coded this yet. I am putting the concept out there, for help on how to approach it. please assist

Comment: @whodat first read this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html and conver you data into pandas df

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi does what I have at the bottom there something you are looking for?

Comment: @whodat you original data is list of lists?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi yes. But I can change it to whatever is needed to solve the use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using 2 data frames find state for each IP, then create new column based on this dictionary data and load into original df.

I think it can be done in more compact way, but still it do the job.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'CA', '192.168.1.0/24'], [2, 'TX', '172.68.7.0/24'], [3, 'NY', '61.141.47.0/24']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'State', 'IP_subnet'])
# replace end of IP
df['IP_subnet'] = df['IP_subnet'].str.replace(r'.0/24', '')

data2 = [[1, '61.141.47.1'], [2, '192.168.1.48'], [3, '172.68.7.124'], [4, '40.32.123.212']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['ID', 'IP'])

# match IP with state
data = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ww = df2[df2['IP'].str.contains(row['IP_subnet'])]
    data[ww['IP'].values[0]] = row['State']

# create State column
state_data = []
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['IP'] in data:
        state_data.append(data.get(row['IP']))
    else:
        state_data.append('NaN')

df2['State'] = state_data
```

Output:

```
   ID             IP State
0   1    61.141.47.1    NY
1   2   192.168.1.48    CA
2   3   172.68.7.124    TX
3   4  40.32.123.212   NaN
```